# trigger.io Error reading file

Tags: trigger.io

I use the forge.file.saveURL to save a JSON object to the local file system, then I use forge.file.String to read the contents and display them on the device.

This works just fine on IOS and Android but it seem on Android after the device has closed the app or force closed it after being open for a while when I reopen the app and try and access the file I get the error message in the console

> Native call file.string with task.params:
>   {"uri":"file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.phonegap.conbop/files/Download/594f9cdc-a791-40ef-a40b-75d16948a9ca"}
>
> [DEBUG] Returned: {"content":{"message":"Error reading
>   file","type":"UNEXPECTED_FAILURE","subtype":null},"callid":"508FE1AD-EB74-4377-8FDA-AA7318457B5C","status":"error"}

I have tested the IOS and this does not seem to happen there, its almost like the file is getting corrupt or something but what is strange is a also use the file.saveURL to save images etc and those work just fine so I'm not sure why this one is having issues.

Comment: Does this happen only when the device is plugged in to a computer? If the SD card is mounted on the computer then the app may not be able to read files on it.

Comment: No this happens without the app being plugged in. I have seen that before with the SD card before but this seems to happen when say I have the app open, I leave my phone for a few hours maybe overnight and open it back up again, the app open but that file is corrupt. I put a work around where I check "isFile" if that is false I will grab the data again and bypass other functions but I would prefer not to have to do that.

Comment: I can also add that it does seem to be consistantly repeatable as I just tried it again on my phone (not plugged in) and again the file got corrupt.

Comment: Can you add what Android version you're testing on and if it's a device or emulator?

Comment: Hi Amir, This happens on all versions of android that I have tested on, both emulator and device. I have tested android 2.3 and 4.0 happens on both.